# Batch file incorrect directory

Tags: c, batch-file

I have a c file inside a directory named tools and a bat file in the root directory, the c file creates a txt that is supposed to be in the same directory as where it is, but when I execute it from the bat file, it is created in the root .

**Batch file**

```
@echo off
tools\titlekey.exe
```

**C file**

```
FILE *f2 = fopen("final.txt", "w+");
```

Comment: You could let the user specify the file to use: `FILE *f2 = fopen(argv[1], "w+"); if (!f2) { perror(argv[1]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` and the batch file would have `tools\titlekey.exe tools\final.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Change the current working directory before you call the program.

```
@echo off
cd tools
titlekey.exe
cd /
```

As @SomethingDark said in the comments, using [`pushd` and `popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) would also be possible and ensure, that the user finds himself in back in the directory he started the batch file from.

```
@echo off
pushd /tools  rem addet the slash to make an absolute path *)
titlekey.exe
popd
```

*) so it doesn't matter what the current working directory is when the batch file is called.

Comment: `cd /` will go to the root directory of the current drive. If that's not what you're trying to do, I suggest `pushd tools` and then `popd` when you're done.

Comment: @SomethingDark "cd / will go to the root directory of the current drive." Yes. From the askers description I figured that he usually calls his batch file from the root directory and probably would want to be there again when the batch file is done. But of course you are right, pushd & popd would have been the more elegant and versatile option.

Comment: I've seen people (incorrectly) refer to the directory where the script is located as "the root directory" and was just being cautious.

Comment: I'm just glad I stumbled on this answer. I've used `pushd/popd` for decades on Linux, but never knew there was a DOS counterpart (of course I'd never looked either)

Comment: Windows uses the backslash as a path separator, not forward slashes. _Whilst it can accept forward slashes, I see no reason to bastardise Windows batch file syntax unnecessarily._ If you take a look at my answer, it does what is required without the need to traverse in and out of directories, and therefore simplifies the process as a single line command.

Answer (score 0):

What about just using the `Start` command?

```bat
@Start /D tools titlekey
```

*Enter `Start /?` at the Command Prompt for the command usage information.*